# css hover state doesnt work after executing js code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar menu, and using js code active item has different background and font color. It works, but after clicking on any item, css line marked bellow as `line x` - doesn't more work. Why is it lost. In js code I didn't touch `:hover` state at all ?

```
<div id="divL">
<div id="sky">SKY</div>
<div id="sea">SEA</div>
<div id="universe">UNI-VERSE</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#divL  div{
    margin:3px 0;
    padding:5px 14px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#divL div:first-of-type {
  background:#ffffff;
    color:#008080;
}
#divL div:hover{  // line x
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#008080;
}
```

JS

```
$("#divL div").click(function () {
$('#divL div').css({'background':'#008080', 'color':'#ffffff'})
$(this).css({'background':'#ffffff', 'color':'#008080'})
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jQuery code is changing the inline style and it is overwriting your CSS file styles.

*As pointed out [in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/):*

> When using .css() as a setter, jQuery modifies the element's style
>   property.

Your code results in:

```
<div id="universe" style="background-color: #fff; color: rgb(0, 128, 128); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">UNI-VERSE</div>
```

I would recommend you to use another style instead of changing the inline styles with jQuery.
You can make use of  [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`removeClass()`](http://jqueryui.com/removeClass/) or even the [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) functions of jQuery.

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uUDeS/1/

**jQuery:**

```
$("#divL div").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
    $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#divL div.inactive {
    background:#008080;
    color:#fff;
}
#divL div.active {
    background:#fff;
    color:#008080;
}
```

Comment: Alvaro, thanks I'll try with `toggleClass()` but I don't understand why is `hover` state changed. There is no such a line in js code

Comment: @SunSky the `hover` state isn't changed - it's still being applied, but it's being overridden by the inline styles applied.

Comment: xdumaine, why is it overridden ? Where is such instruction in js code ? There is no `:hover` state line in js.

Comment: Inline style override embedded styles. It has a higher specificity. The inline styles applied are more important than the :hover style.

Comment: Moob, where is js line to change `hover` state ? It doesn't exist !

Comment: @SunSky, you are NOT changin the `hover` style in your CSS styles. You are changing the HTML code of the site and adding an inline css style which overwrites the ones you define.

Comment: @Alvaro's fiddle just needs more specific rules for the hover to work. `#divL div:hover, #divL div.inactive:hover, #divL div.active:hover {background:#ffffff;color:#008080;}` as per [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUDeS/1/)

Comment: @SunSky you need to [read up](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/). As we're trying to explain: the JS is not changing anything about the `hover` state or styles. It's the CSS specificity that's causing you to not see those rules applied, because a higher specificity one is applied.